# Applications downs due to heavy MySQL server load

Tags: mysql, percona

We have a 2GB Digital Ocean server, and it is dedicated for a MySQL server of other two PHP servers. we are using Percona MySQL Server 5.6 on this server. We configured MySQL replication and these configuration is working fine

Our issue is sometime our site monitoring tools reporting that some of the URL hosted with this server is down (May be this is happening once in a week or two). When I am checking, I could see that Mysql Master server load is too much high (May be 35 - 40), so the MySQL server was not responded. @ that I usually do a MySQl service restart, this restart cause to server load become normal and  the sites started working after service restart.

This is a back-end MySQL database server of 20-25 PHP applications (WordPress, Drupal and some custom applications server).

Here are my questions,

1. Why this server load automatically goes down, after a spikes happens?
2. Is there any way in which database is causing issues? So that I can identify the application too.
3. How can I identify the root cause of this issues

Comment: usually these are caused by long running mysql queries.  best to find and optimize these.  i'd suspect missing indexes and cron jobs gone crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your working dataset, a 2GB server providing access for 20-25 PHP applications (WordPress, Drupal and some custom applications server) could be the issue.

For example, if you have a 1.4GB buffer pool (assuming all tables are InnnoDB) and 10GB of data, then your various applications could end up competing for resources, such as I/O, buffer pool pages, Adaptive Hash Index, query cache. They could also, assuming caching is used, be invalidating theit caches within a similar timeframe, thus sending expensive queries to the database.

Whilst a load of 50 is something that you would normally want to avoid, the load average is not something that you should concern yourself with if showing in isolation.

> The use of the uninterruptible state has since grown in the Linux
>   kernel, and nowadays includes uninterruptible lock primitives. If the
>   load average is a measure of demand in terms of running and waiting
>   threads (and not strictly threads wanting hardware resources), then
>   they are still working the way we want them to.

http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html

If the issue is happening once per week then it is starting to sound like a batch process, or cache expiration issue - too much happening at once for the resources available.

The best thing to do is to monitor and look for the cause. Since you are already using Percona Server, using [PMM](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-and-management/deploy/index.html) should give you the perfect insight to find the cause, although it works with Oracle MySQL, MariaDB, Aurora, etc. You can try a demo to see the insights that you can gain:
https://pmmdemo.percona.com. The software is Open Source and free to use.

You can look in [QAN](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-and-management/using.html) to find the most expensive queries, whilst looking at Prometheus data to give an insight into the host itself. There are [some recommendations](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-and-management/conf-mysql.html) to get the most from PMM, depending upon your flavour of MySQL.